# Using Mustache lambda functions in ERB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mustache

I'm trying to share my Mustache templates in Rails across the server and the client on the lines of [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/295-sharing-mustache-templates).

All is well, except that I'm unable to figure out where and how to put the definition of a lambda function on the server side.

Let's say my `html.erb` looks like:

```
<% if params['client_side'].nil? %>
  <%= render 'template', :mustache => @post %>
<% else %>
  <script type="text/template" id="template">
    <%= render 'template' %>
  </script>    
<% end %>
```

The Mustache handler looks like this (exactly as in the Railscast):

```
module MustacheTemplateHandler
  def self.call(template)
    if template.locals.include? 'mustache'
      "Mustache.render(#{template.source.inspect}, mustache).html_safe"
    else
      "#{template.source.inspect}.html_safe"
    end
  end
end

ActionView::Template.register_template_handler(:mustache, MustacheTemplateHandler)
```

Now for the following template:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<div>
  {{#marked}}{{content}}{{/marked}}
</div>
```

the lambda `marked` is easy to handle in JavaScript, but how can I define it in my Rails code to render `content` using [Redcarpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet)?

### Update

Since posting this, I have tried to expand on the idea of helper functions in the screencast. I now have

```
<% if params['client_side'].nil? %>
  <%= render 'template', :mustache => process(@post) %>
<% else %>
...
```

The `process` is defined in `ApplicationHelper` as

```
def process(obj)
  {
    marked: lambda {|text| markdown(Mustache.render(text))}
  }
end
```

This has two problems:

1. `text` inside the (Ruby) lambda function is indeed `'{{content}}'`, but `Mustache.render(text)` fails to do anything with it — it's returning an empty string.
2. The above code will now only render the `marked` field and I haven't been able to find a way to retain the other (unprocessed) attributes of the `author` object (e.g. `title`). `obj.attributes` seems like a promising start, but I don't know how to combine the processed response for `marked` with the other `attributes` even if #1 above worked.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working myself. The `process` method in `ApplicationHelper` now looks like this (using the new lambda syntax):

```
def process(obj)
  obj['marked'] = ->(text) { markdown(Mustache.render(text, obj)) }
  obj.attributes
end
```

This will now catch all invocations of `marked` in any template.